# How to remove extra space between the \ref and text

Tags: xetex, ref

How to remove extra spaces between \ref{...} and text?
This is the example:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\caption{Some text\label{tab1}}
\begin{tabular*}{500pt}{@{\extracolsep\fill}lccD{.}{.}{3}c@{\extracolsep\fill}}
Table information
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}
\end{table}
(see Table \ref{tab3}, O9)
```

[image: Example text result]

**EDIT**

Thats the preambla of my prject:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{float}
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=cyan,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\articletype{Article Type}%
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{caption}
```

Comment: Please give a *complete* example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Normally, what you describe does not happen. So some additional code in your preamble or some package introduce this space.

Comment: Unrelated, but don't use `center` inside of `table`, this gives improper spacing. Instead use `\centering`.

Comment: the fragment you show should not produce a space after `\ref`. Do not post disconnected fragments, post a single small complete example that produces the output shown.

Comment: `\articletype` is used in several publishers' classes. Without knowing which one you're using it becomes pure guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your preamble code fragment is not complete. In it are missed

  - document class (assumable `article`)
  - package `dcolumn` for used `D` columns in table
  - contain undefined command `\articletype{Article Type}`
- Package `hyperref` had to ve load tha last in preamble (with rare exceptions which are not present in your code snippets)
- Table is slightly unusual (two `@{\extracolsep\fill}` instructions)

With completing and correction your preamble and table:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{float}
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{dcolumn, longtable, ltablex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=cyan,
    filecolor=magenta,
    urlcolor=cyan,
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\caption{Some text}
\label{tab1}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep\fill}lccD{.}{.}{3}c@{\extracolsep\fill}}
    \hline
Table information & text    & text  & 123.456   \\
    \hline
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
(see Table \ref{tab1}, O9)
\end{document}
```

I can't reproduce your problem:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Please, next time at question provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which reproduce your problem. Merging your code fragments, adding missed packages, document class may remove a cause of your problem.